# Plugging phone into laptop charges laptop instead of phone

Tags: usb, charging, macos

When I plug my father's Xiaomi 5X into my MacBook Pro, it shows up as a charger on the MacBook and I don't get the usual USB options on the phone. Tried it on two Macs with same result. Also tried my Pixel 2 with the same cable and that worked as expected.

Is there some setting in either the phone or laptop that I can change to make it recognise the phone for what it is?

Answer (score 7):

This is called PD charging. There should be a setting in connection dialog. Also there should be the same options in Developer Settings
[image: PD charging]

Comment: That makes sense. Trouble is the connection dialog doesn't appear on the 5X like it does on the Pixel.

Comment: this happens to me often when enabled developer settings - each time i connect i have to navigate to developer settings and select "MTP" again (it does not remember nor show a dialog)