# Connect via ADB to a physical X86 via USB

Tags: adb, usb, lenovo, android-x86

I have Android-x86 (version 9.0-r2) running in a Lenovo MIIX-320 and I have another PC running Linux. From the Linux host I can connect to any other Android device using an USB cable . But I can't connect to the Lenovo. Googling around I noticed that the vast majority of people connect to Android-x86 host via ADB using the network, what is not an option in this case.
Is there any service in the Android-x86 that I should use to allow ADB connections using USB?

Comment: USB is a master-slave system. The USB ports of a PC work as master. When connecting two PCs via USB both PCs want to work as master which don't work. I am not sure if a software like Android x86 can on software level "reprogram" one USB port as USB slave so that communication is possible. Another problem is that an USB PC-PC connection is physically impossible unless you are using USB-C.

Comment: In this case I'm using USB  Type C.

Comment: Then this question also applies to you: [Is it possible to connect two PCs via USB C?](https://superuser.com/questions/1215710)

Comment: check if you have such setting in developer options: [Plugging phone into laptop charges laptop instead of phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213286) also this might helpful: [Terminal emulator on Android device: Can I communicate with the terminal on my Linux machine over bluetooth?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224078)