# How do I get a USB stick with an adapter to work with an Android phone (rather than a tablet)?

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go

I have a USB stick that lights up when it is plugged in.  I have attached it to laptops and tablets (with adapters), and it lights up and works well.  When I attach it to cell phones (through the same adapter that I do with tablets), it does not light up.  Is there a setting to enable the Android 7.x phone to give power to the attached devices (the way Android tablets do)?

Update: My phone does not support OTG.

Comment: your android device must support [USB-OTG](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_OTG)

Comment: regarding your other question https://android.stackexchange.com/q/213286

Comment: If your hardware or kernel doesn't support OTG, there's no way to use your phone in USB hosts mode with any USB device. Just to be sure: [Is there a definite way to know if my phone supports USB-OTG or not?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218728/218526)

Answer (score -1):

[How to set the default USB behavior in Android 10](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-set-the-default-usb-behavior-in-android-10/)

When you plug something into your Android device, it will behave in accordance with how you have configured the action. With Android 10, you have five options:

1. **File transfer/Android Auto**: Transfer files to and from PC/Android or
   open Android Auto.
2. **USB tethering**: Behave as an external network interface for the PC.
3. **MIDI**: Used when connecting your phone to a MIDI device (such as a
   digital keyboard).
4. **PTP**: When connected, your device will appear to the PC as a digital
   camera.
5. **No data transfer**: No action taken.

Steps to change the default USB dehaviour in Android 10:

First, you are going to want to enable Developer options

1. Open Settings. Tap About Phone.
2. Scroll down to the bottom.
3. Tap Build Number (seven times) until you are informed that
   Developer Options have been enabled.

Now that you have Developer Options enabled, you can set the default USB behaviour.

1. Navigate to the developer options: (**System > advanced > developer options**, may differ from device to device)
2. Within Developer options, navigate to (in my case) **Networking > `Default USB configuration`**

Comment: your answer is not related to question

Comment: What you described is related to USB device mode settings. OP wants to use it in host mode i.e. attach a USB Mass Storage device to it.